# Angular - How to cache an image indefinetly, regardless of the server's response headers

Tags: javascript, angular, cache-control, angular-http-interceptors

I have an angular application on my own domain, that displays images from google storage like this:

```
<img src="googleUrl..."/>
```

The default `Cache-Control` is set to **3600 seconds** which is way too low for me, because I want to cache the images for 1 week (the images on the storage change very rarely).

I tried to create an `HttpInterceptor` but it does not intercept the request that the `src` of the img makes.

I also tried to create a pipe and set a `Cache-Control` header but, the server being google, it gives me a `Cross-Origin` error. This is how I implemented it:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'cacheResource',
})
export class CacheResourcePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
    transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=2.592.000',
        });
        return this.http
            .get(url, {
                headers,
                responseType: 'blob',
            })
            .pipe(map((val) => URL.createObjectURL(val)));
    }
}
```

And then called like this:

```
<img [src]="'googleUrl.com' | cacheResource | async" />
```

(The pipe approach works with files stored on the same domain but I don't have this possibility)

Is there any way to achieve the long cache that I need without changing the server?

Comment: Is it possible to add images in local host and load image from local host first and if not found then go for http service. You can do this using pipe too

Comment: Im not quite sure i grasped the whole idea, if you could be a bit more clear i'd appriciate it. Thanks regardless, and i will try something similar to see if it works.

Comment: you can convert that blob into base64 string and then store it in local storage.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript